# Infowindow gmaps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

this is my code for multiple markers: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IeKxEhA0M4ggzO8ENvKvHYG2Z1CIBH8WthcwJYxc6aU/pub

i need after click on marker show infowindow...

there is example how i want it but i need it to my different script...
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global array for your markers: you defined each of them inside the setMarkers() function like this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var beach = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            shape: shape,
            title: beach[0],
            zIndex: beach[3]
        });
  }
```

And you create your infowindow after:

```
var markers = new Array();

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.864372, 19.311537)
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                    mapOptions);
  setMarkers(map, beaches);

  for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
      'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
      'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
      'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
      'Heritage Site.</p>'+
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
      'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
  });
  }
}
```

Comment: It's also really useful to put your markers into a global array if you want to update them or if you want to create an edit function : markers[0].setOptions({ draggable: true });

Comment: It doesn`t work but i think that your option is correct. Can be somewhere small mistake which i don`t see?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you define your infowindow (content, element and event) inside the loop in setMarkers(). You can also make global your map variable.